# Spotify Web Service XML Schema issue

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, spotify

I'm trying to deserialize a Spotify Web Service call and I'm getting the following error: `There is an error in XML document (1, 2).` I'm thinking it might be because I'm using the wrong XML Namespace, but I can't find one that works. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the code I'm using

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Album), "http://www.spotify.com/ns/music/1");
Album a = new Album();
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("../../AlbumSearch.xml"))
{
    try
    {
        a = (Album)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}\n\nInner Exception: {1}", e.Message, e.InnerException);
    }
}
```

Outputs

```
Message: There is an error in XML document (1, 2).

Inner Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: <albums xmlns='http://www.spo
tify.com/ns/music/1'> was not expected.
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderAlbum.
Read7_Album()
```

Example of XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<albums xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" xmlns="http://www.spotify.com/ns/music/1">
  <opensearch:Query role="request" startPage="1" searchTerms="foo"/>
  <opensearch:totalResults>255</opensearch:totalResults>
  <opensearch:startIndex>0</opensearch:startIndex>
  <opensearch:itemsPerPage>100</opensearch:itemsPerPage>
  <album href="spotify:album:1zCNrbPpz5OLSr6mSpPdKm">
    <name>Greatest Hits</name>
    <artist href="spotify:artist:7jy3rLJdDQY21OgRLCZ9sD">
      <name>Foo Fighters</name>
    </artist>
    <id type="upc">884977373295</id>
    <popularity>0.84</popularity>
    <availability>
      <territories>
        AD AR AT AU BE BG BO BR CA CH CL CO CR CY CZ DE DK DO EC EE ES FI FR GB GR GT HK HN HU IE IS IT LI LT LU LV MC MT MX MY NI NL NO NZ PA PE PH PL PT PY RO SE SG SI SK SV TR TW US UY
      </territories>
    </availability>
  </album>
</albums>
```

Answer (score 0):

What does your Album class decl look like?

Do you have a `[XmlRoot("albums", Namespace = "http://www.spotify.com/ns/music/1")]` on there?